# How to respond to an OAuth 2.0 Authorization Endpoint request that fails due to invalid response_type?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

From [RFC 6749 section 4.2.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2.1):

> If the resource owner denies the access request or if the request fails for reasons other than a missing or invalid redirection URI, the authorization server informs the client by adding the following parameters to the **fragment component** of the redirection URI

From [RFC 6749 section 4.1.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1):

> If the resource owner denies the access request or if the request fails for reasons other than a missing or invalid redirection URI, the authorization server informs the client by adding the following parameters to the **query component** of the redirection URI

The former applies to Implicit Grant flow requests to the Authorization Endpoint; the latter applies to Authorization Code flow requests to the Authorization Endpoint. The difference is indicated by the `response_type` parameter the client sends to the Authorization Endpoint; `token` indicates Implicit flow, and `code` indicates Authorization Code flow. Therefore, if an error occurs, the logic is as follows:

```
if response_type == 'token'
  error response in fragment
else if response_type == 'code'
  error response in query string
else
  ????????????????????
end
```

The spec appears to leave it open what to do in the final "else". A possible client error would be to include a `response_type` parameter with a value other than `code` or `token`. This may not meet the criteria for an un-redirectable error, so an authorization server should redirect to the `redirect_uri` if possible with a suitable error response (`error=invalid_request` or possibly `error=unsupported_response_type`).

But where does that error parameter go? Query component or fragment? Both? Should this after all be treated as a non-redirectable error like an invalid `redirect_uri`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading RFC 6749 carefully, it can be found that a client can access the authorization endpoint without having registered its redirect URI(s) in advance if some conditions meet. The conditions are (1) confidential, (2) implicit and (3) explicit redirect_uri parameter. In this case, response_type needs to be determined before redirect_uri is determined. This means that there is a case where unsupported_response_type error cannot be reported to the client by redirect. So, we don't always have to report unsupported_response_type error by redirect (because we cannot do it in this case).

If I were you, I would just send "400 Bad Request" to the client with an error message. IMHO, clients that cannot specify even response_type correctly are unqualified to receive responses via redirect and should be notified earlier of such a basic error during their early development phases.

Comment: This is the same judgment I came to. Thanks for the answer!